# Python app scheduler doesn't run the same on systemd

Tags: python, background, apscheduler

I have a python service that uses a background scheduler to run different tasks. It keeps our database up to date with other APIs using HTTP GETs and POSTs.

We had this running on heroku without trouble. We recently moved our production box on OVH. When I run it using

```
python runtasks.py
```

everything works fine. When I run it in the background using

```
python runtasks.py &
```

or using this systemd unit file

```
[Unit]
...

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /path/to/python/file/runtasks.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The process runs without errors, however it does not work for more than 1 hour.

I've used the journalctl to get the process logs

```
Aug 10 13:10:23 ns504338.ip-192-99-1.net bash[23763]:
WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job "Foobar.run 
(trigger: interval[0:00:20], next run at: 2015-08-10 13:10:23 EDT)" 
skipped: maxim
Aug 10 13:10:43 ns504338.ip-192-99-1.net bash[23763]: 
WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job "Foobar.run 
(trigger: interval[0:00:20], next run at: 2015-08-10 13:10:43 EDT)" 
skipped: maxim
Aug 10 13:11:03 ns504338.ip-192-99-1.net bash[23763]: 
WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job "Foobar.run 
(trigger: interval[0:00:20], next run at: 2015-08-10 13:11:03 EDT)" 
skipped: maxim
...
```

These warnings are present less frequently when it is running correctly. And they are among other log messages.

My current assumption is a missing env variable or relative path. I'm currently investigating, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Based on those log messages, I would say the job gets stuck and does not finish before the next run is scheduled. The log line looks like it's been cut in the middle.